# Azure media services sdk returns error on encoding to Adaptive Bitrate MP4 Set

Tags: php, azure, encode, azure-media-services

Im new on Azure media services and trying it through php. I am able to upload  the file on remote using Multiple Bitrate but it shows not supported. It does generate the URL to access it but shows a MPE_FEATURE_USAGE_FORBIDDEN, i have also enabled the public access from Azure dashboard but still i dont know why it shows that. Then I tried Adaptive bitrate as shown in code but now its not even allowing me to encode it and shows error. In multiple bitrate, im guessing its also a case of encoder error.

```
function encodeToAdaptiveBitrateMP4Set($restProxy, $asset) {
// 2.1 retrieve the latest 'Media Encoder Standard' processor version
$mediaProcessor = $restProxy->getLatestMediaProcessor('Media Encoder Standard');

print "Using Media Processor: {$mediaProcessor->getName()} version {$mediaProcessor->getVersion()}\r\n";

// 2.2 Create the Job; this automatically schedules and runs it
$outputAssetName = "Encoded " . $asset->getName();
$outputAssetCreationOption = Asset::OPTIONS_NONE;
$taskBody = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><taskBody><inputAsset>JobInputAsset(0)</inputAsset><outputAsset assetCreationOptions="' . $outputAssetCreationOption . '" assetName="' . $outputAssetName . '">JobOutputAsset(0)</outputAsset></taskBody>';

$task = new Task($taskBody, $mediaProcessor->getId(), TaskOptions::NONE);
$task->setConfiguration('H264 Adaptive Bitrate MP4 Set 1080p');

$job = new Job();
$job->setName('Encoding Job');

$job = $restProxy->createJob($job, array($asset), array($task));

print "Created Job with Id: {$job->getId()}\r\n";

// 2.3 Check to see if the Job has completed
$result = $restProxy->getJobStatus($job);

$jobStatusMap = array('Queued', 'Scheduled', 'Processing', 'Finished', 'Error', 'Canceled', 'Canceling');

while($result != Job::STATE_FINISHED && $result != Job::STATE_ERROR && $result != Job::STATE_CANCELED) {
    print "Job status: {$jobStatusMap[$result]}\r\n";
    sleep(5);
    $result = $restProxy->getJobStatus($job);
}

if ($result != Job::STATE_FINISHED) {
    print "The job has finished with a wrong status: {$jobStatusMap[$result]}\r\n";
    exit(-1);
}

print "Job Finished!\r\n";

// 2.4 Get output asset
$outputAssets = $restProxy->getJobOutputMediaAssets($job);
$encodedAsset = $outputAssets[0];

print "Asset encoded: name={$encodedAsset->getName()} id={$encodedAsset->getId()}\r\n";

return $encodedAsset;
```

}

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: The preset you used seems not be list at https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/mt269960.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using wrong preset for a given media processor. Your job encoding probably failing with something like:

```
"An error has occurred. Stage: ParsePreset. Code: Microsoft.Cloud.Media.Encoding.PresetException.

Microsoft.Cloud.Media.Encoding.PresetException: Invalid Preset String: H264 Adaptive Bitrate MP4 Set 1080p"
```

Try using encoder "Media Encoder Standard" with preset "H264 Multiple Bitrate 1080p". As Gary mentioned you can find full list of supported preset names at https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/mt269960.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396